# How can I write columns 'name' attribute to excel in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
df.index.name='class1'
df.columns.name='class2'
df.to_excel('...')
```

The index name attribute 'class1' can be written normally, but the columns 'name' attribute 'class2' can't. Please note that I am not talking about the columns name 'A and B'. How can I write it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have provided, you should try setting the column names with `df.columns = ['column name 1', 'column name 2']` and so on before you export. If that answer does not help, could you provide some of the data and commands you are putting in along with the output you are getting? That could be helpful in resolving this.

Comment: I know this 'columns' attribute, but i am talking about the 'name' attribute. In fact, the dataframe has its own column names already. I made some updates, hope you could understand it better.